# Unable to read variables in shell script running in C++

Tags: c++, shell, sh

I have a shell script that goes as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

TESTOUTDIR=/home/speedster/test_dir

echo "Hello"
echo $TESTOUTDIR
```

When I run this directly from the command line, it prints "Hello" and the TESTOUTDIR variable which I have set as expected.

Now I am running this from a C++ program. My program is as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    string runCommand = "/test.sh";
    system(runCommand.c_str());
}
```

When I run this I get the output as only "Hello". The variable is not getting printed. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: How did you set `$TESTOUTDIR`? Have you `export`ed it?

Comment: Try `TESTOUTDIR=foo my_prog`. Try `echo $TESTOUTDIR` before running `my_prog` (or whatever it's called). This looks like a problem setting the environment, not in C++

Comment: @speedster01: Hmm, I'm not a Bash guy so I don't know, but chances are `.bashrc` has no effect in the sub shell spawned from the C++ program. Also note that the shebang of the script references to `sh` not `bash`. Even if `sh` is a link to `bash` it might behave differently when called as `sh`. Maybe that are some pointers to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a comment, not an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I tested your code, and the `TESTOUTDIR` variable prints fine for me. Below is what I ran to test your code:

```sh
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

TESTOUTDIR=/home/speedster/test_dir

echo "Hello"
echo $TESTOUTDIR
```

```cpp
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    string runCommand = "./test.sh";
    system(runCommand.c_str());
}
```

```sh
$ g++ test.cpp -o test_exec
$ ./test_exec 
Hello
/home/speedster/test_dir
```

I tested your code on Ubuntu 18.04 with g++ 7.5.0.

My `sh` executable is a symbolic link to `dash`, which is a POSIX shell. I also tested changing your shebang in `test.sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, and I continued to see your `TESTOUTDIR` printed as expected.

I suggest you confirm `/test.sh` contains the contents you expect.

Comment: IMHO this is a valid answer, with code and explainations. And anyway it contains way too much code to fit in a comment...